# How do I render a helper properly within a Razor helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Imagine this scenario...

```
@helper TabTest()
{
    using (Html.BeginPortlet())
    {
        <strong>hello</strong>
    }
}
```

If I call it in the Razor file then it renders fine.

```
@TabTest()
```

Output: `<div class="portlet"><strong>hello</strong></div>`

If I call it using another helper... eg: `@Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent(TabTest())` then the rendering is not the same.

Output:

```
<div class="portlet"></div>
<strong>hello</strong>
```

This is just a crude example and I've removed the redundant code to simplify.  I assume it is something to do with the way the pipeline is written but I see no way to fix it.

I've read things about viewcontexts and textwriters but don't know how they would apply here.

**The helper:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderBootstrapTabContent(this HtmlHelper helper, HelperResult content)
{
    return content.ToHtmlString();
}
```

The `BeginPortlet` method is custom and very similar to `BeginForm` and uses the `IDisposable` interface.

What can I do to fix this weird error?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case my question didn't make sense to you I found someone else who did what I was trying to explain just without calling them in the same way.  http://web.archive.org/web/20170504100102/http://jordanwallwork.co.uk/2012/07/nested-htmlhelpers-with-razor-and-using/

After reading everything I could online I still found no answer.  It seems like perhaps nobody else has either tried this (or knew not to).

I finally fixed the issue by rewriting the RenderBootstrapTabContent method in the same way as BeginPortlet using a helper and `IDisposable`. So now instead of writing...

```
@Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent(TabTest())
```

I now use

```
using (Html.BeginBootstrapTabContent()) { @TabTest() }
```

I've wasted a lot of time over the last few days on this so I help this might help you.

If you've got a better idea please let me know.